# Getting CPU clock signal out of computer (as to measure externally)

Tags: clock, cpu, computer-architecture, computers

I've been searching on the internet some clock generator module capable of reaching up to 1GHz, when I just realized that the machine I'm using to search has one CPU with its own 2.5-3.0 GHz clock...  Is there a way to extract the clock signal out from the motherboard? Something like a spot where I can nail my oscilloscope probe and say "look dude, that thing going up and down at 2.5GHz is my computer's clock!"

Comment: The CPU operates at 2+ GHz internally, but it interfaces the outside world at the PCI-e frequency, which was 100 MHz some time ago, not sure about now. The DRAM is also 133 (or more nowadays) MHz, but nothing close to GHz.

Comment: @anrieff um, that's wrong.  The IO bus clock on DDR4-3200 is 1.6 GHz.

Comment: at 2.5 GHz, you won't be doing much 'nailing my oscilloscope probe'. If you can afford a probe that works at 2.5-3 GHz, you can afford any of a number of PLL dev boards that can be had for a few tens of dollars/euro

Comment: You'll have better luck putting your WiFi card in some single-tone test mode (if you happen to figure out how that is possible - has to be possible for FCC certification), and using that.
Or, as @JorenVaes said, you know, PLL boards are far cheaper than the oscilloscope probes (leave alone the oscilloscopes) needed to "distortion-freely" measure this.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - didn't know that, my memories of it are rather dated. Doesn't that mean that the OP can measure the DDR IO clock, and get his GHz-grade signal?

Comment: no, @anrieff, he can't, for reasons that Joren explained :)

Comment: Hey, Guillermo, albeit asking for component recommendations is off-topic here, I think we'd like to see a question where you describe what exactly you need that 2.5 to 3.0 GHz clock for, what the cost etc constraints are, and what the problem is you're trying to solve in the bigger picture :)

Comment: @Marcus Müller Fair enough  :-)    Actually I just want to test some ASICs response; the thing with CPU's clock is a doubt that jumped while looking for a clock generator module to buy (which is what I'm going to do I guess, as suggested above...)

Comment: even then it seems odd to me that a lab is equipped with a scope capable of measuring that kind of signal, but not a signal generator

Comment: @Joren Vaes I have some signal generators capable of reaching that speed, but then signal level gets dramatically decreased (to the order of mV, while I require 3.3 V to feed the ASICs)

Comment: What kind of signal generator are you using? How are you measuring this? As I said earlier, unless you have probes and scopes made to work at these frequencies, and you properly probe everything and use the right terminations, your not going to get sensible measurements.

Comment: as mentioned internal clocks are generated often from a 100mhz reference clock and an internal pll, could be a different speed reference clock too.  you may see external pcie signals, ddr signals and network signals in the ones to 10 or more ghz.  you will need a scope that costs about as much as a house and each probe costs about as much as a used car.

Comment: the cpu clock itself though doesnt generally make sense to bring it out of the package on to the board.

Comment: @anrieff depends on the generation of ddr I supposed but I recently saw ddr4 on our scope and dont remember the clock being continous.  have to solder down disposable probes for those frequencies and as mentioned above have a scope that costs about as much as a nice house.  (the disposable probes are not as expensive as the handhelds, not tossing away $10K per disposable probe, probably tens to hundreds but I dont know).  Were able to see and debug the ddr4 interface though.  1600mhz  LPDDR4 3200.

Comment: you hold your mouth right and the differential probe could see them but when trying to look at multiple signals at the same time relative to each other, cant get three or four people around holding probes, someone to run the scope and someone to run the keyboard to get the ddr interface to do stuff, so using the solder down probes was the way to go.

Comment: pcie and high speed networking also will have some to a lot of ghz, up to 10+ghz, but not a clock, the idle patterns have a good transition density but its not a clock, you could put a probe down and say see theres X ghz with the right scope.  usually you are looking at the eye though, not an individual capture.

Comment: you can generate signals in these frequencies with fpgas with serdes interfaces.  you can buy eval boards for these fpgas and generate clocks if you want rather than more complicated protocols.  the fpgas are as inexpensive as $10-$15 the eval boards are no doubt overly complicated and hundreds of dollars...and then there is the license for their software to build projects for that part...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The internal core frequency is generated from an external 133.3MHz BCLK_DP/BCLK_DN differential clock input (using on-chip PLL to multiply the clock frequency). See, for example, [this](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/core-i7-900-ee-and-desktop-processor-series-32nm-datasheet-vol-1.pdf) Intel document.

You won't directly find the very high core frequency signals on the PCB.

This is true of even very small (relatively speaking) microprocessors and microcontrollers these days- a relatively low frequency external clock drives an on-chip PLL to multiply the clock up for on-chip use. For example, the ARM chip I'm using right now has a 12MHz external crystal but operates at 300MHz on chip.

Answer (score 0):

Assume a bit of metal atop the CPU, with 1pF capacitance down into the various aluminum or copper paths on the silicon. Assume the clock lines are 2volts with 20 picosecond edges. And assume this bit of metal feeds a 50_ohm coax into a spectrum analyzer. What can be detected?

I = C * dV/dT = 1pf * 2v/20pS = 0.1 amps, which would produce 5 volts across the 50 ohm termination in the SA. But in that case, the 50_ohm environment is limiting the signal, not the 1pF.

Answer (score -2):

I realize you are shopping for an RF generator.

**Here is one such VCO [design](https://www.electroschematics.com/756/10-to-1000-mhz-oscillator/). 10 MHz to 1000 MHz Oscillator**

[image: ![enter image description here]  Critical Layout not included.

======================================

To see your CPU internal clock:

All you need is a coax with a small coil loop probe and a spectrum analyzer to detect the emissions of your clock and harmonics. Getting the probe under the MOBO CPU might be hard however.

The PLL clock is inside the CPU so it is not hardware accessible.

The easier way is to get your video driver to display the CPU clock when you point to the upper right hand corner.

I am using an 8 core i8 with 8GB on Win8.1x64

Here cropped is the normal usage with a browser and a few other apps running , then loading up another app.

[image]

Then sliding the mouse down reveals the usage per top consuming app thread.

[image]

```
    A new version of the Filter Design Tool is scheduled to launch on January 23 2019. 
The new Filter Design Tool will enable you to:

Evaluate performance using figures of merit and features for component sensitivity analysis
Use dynamic charts to compare multiple filter responses
Receive recommendations on operational amplifiers based on inputs
Calculate values of passive components to complete your filter design
```